# Return result value with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to implement click debouncing with RxJava in WebView.
For example, user clicks links rapidly, i want to treat only first click.
First, i thought `throttleFirst` is good for this.

```
  private final BehaviorSubject<String> urlLoading = BehaviorSubject.create();

  private final Observable<String> throttled =  urlLoading.throttleFirst(CLICK_THROTTLE_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);  

  //...
  throttled.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(String url) {
      something(url); // :/
    }
  });
  //...

  // WebView callback
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // return something(); // original

    // i want to throttle events and return something() if it's ok or return just true for debounced events
    urlLoading.onNext(url);
    return ... ?
  }
```

`throttleFirst` works fine, but I noticed I can't return value this way.

**Question:**
How can I return value with RxJava when methods that has return type like `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`?
or Shouldn't I use Rx with such case? (go another way like change flag by `Handler#postDelayed`?)

Comment: RxJava doesn't seem to be a good match for this task.

Answer (score 0):

What you want it to listen to the **first** click that `throttled` will emit.

As you want to return a `boolean`, you'll have to be *synchronous* and then to be *blocking*.

What you can do, with RxJava (not tested) :

- emit `something(url);` result
- `take(1)` to take the first event
- `toBloking`to block your RxJava stream and be synchronous.
- return that value

example :

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

     urlLoading.onNext(url);
     return throttler
                .map(url -> something(url))
                .take(1)
                .toBlocking()
                .single();
  }
```

Don't forget to remove your throttler `subsription` code.

Comment: thx, but this way produces new observable each time, doesn't work well